# AngularJS pagination only shows one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls version: 0.14.3 to paginate some result i bring from some database, the problem is that the pagination always looks like this:

```
 << < 1 > >>
```

It doesn't matter if set it up with fixed values or with dynamic values, it stays always the same.
Here is my html code:

```
<uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItemsMapfre"
                    ng-model="bigCurrentPageMapfre" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm"
                    boundary-links="true" ng-change="pageChangedMapfre()" id="pagMapfre"
                    first-text="&laquo;" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;"
                    last-text="&raquo;" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;"></uib-pagination>
```

the javascript:

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller("ctrl",["$http","$scope","servicio",function($http,$scope,servicio){

         $scope.paginationMapfre = {
            currentPage: 1,
            maxSize: 5,
            totalItems :50
        };

    $scope.init=function(){


    //some petitions to the database
        servicio.load(url_comentarios+"@mapfre_mx'&page="+$scope.paginationMapfre.currentPage).then(function(info){
            $scope.comentariosMapfre=info.data.content; //content to paginate
             $scope.paginationMapfre.totalItems = info.data.totalElements; //total elements

        });




        $scope.pageChangedMapfre = function(){
            servicio.load(url_comentarios+"@mapfre_mx'&page="+$scope.bigCurrentPageMapfre).then(function(info){
                $scope.comentariosMapfre=info.data.content; //update the content with another petition to the DB
            });
        }



    }

}]);
```

I not sure what i'm missing/doing wrong, why it doesn't work? i was following the code from the angular site.
**Note:** the results from the DB are always more than 10, so it should paginationMapfre.totalItems should update when the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pagination directive you're setting `total-items` to `bigTotalItemsMapfre`

```
<uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItemsMapfre" ...
```

Are you setting `bigTotalItemsMapfre` to the array length anywhere?

Looking at your controller's code it should rather be:

```
<uib-pagination total-items="paginationMapfre.totalItems" ...
or 
<uib-pagination total-items="paginationMapfre.length" ...
```

Comment: oh, i think i forgot to update that, X/, yeah that did it, thanks a lot!

Comment: This helped because I was referencing the length of a filtered array in `total-items`, but it was in an inner scope that was not available to the `uib-pagination`, so it was manifesting by only showing a single page.